# Office 365 Add-In Excel - External Data

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office365api, excel-addins

I'm looking for some guidance on how to approach an Excel add-in for Office 365 that is based on the Javascript APIs.

The purpose of the add-in is to allow users to customize their own excel file using data from their account on a website. The data would be something as static/simple as a Company Name or it can be something more variable such as "All Contacts" for that company.

What is the best practice in approaching a solution of pulling in external data, including data that would vary from company to company since some company records may have 4 contacts to display while another may have 10.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying to do the same thing. What I have done is created a Seperate REST API and hosted it on Server. and Trying and accessing APIs from AddIn. However, somehow i cant reference my JQuery and so not able to call my API correctly.